# Why is single virtual inheritance not enough to resolve the dreaded diamond problem?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

```
struct B { int i; };
struct D1 : virtual B {};
struct D2 : B {};  // <-- not virtual
struct DD : D1, D2 {};
```

Having coded above, still the compiler demands `D2` also to be `virtual`:

```
DD d;
d.i = 0; // error: request for member `i' is ambiguous
```

What I don't understand is, once you have prompted compiler that `B` is `virtual` with respect to `DD` (via `D1`) then why it still `i` is ambiguous ?

(If my memory serves correct, the older VC++ (in 2006), was capable enough to make out this just with single `virtual` inheritance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

B is not virtual with respect to DD - it is virtual with respect to D1. At the time D2 is created, it contains a full copy of B. So now DD has two implementations of B: one as part of D2, and one at the end (pointed by D1). And having two copies of `i`, using it is indeed ambiguous.

Had D2 also used virtual inheritance, instead of containing a copy of B, it would have contained a pointer to the instance of B that D1 is also pointing at, and DD would have contained only one instance of B.

I'll try to illustrate the memory layouts, hope this comes out right...:

Your case, with one virtual inheritance and one non-virtual -

```
|    D1    |   D2 + B |    B    |
+--+-------+----------+---------+
 |   vptr to B           ^
 +-----------------------|
```

Having both D1 and D2 inherit virtually -

```
|   D1   |   D2   |   B   |
+--+-----+---+----+-------+
 |         |         ^
 +---------+---------|
```

Answer (score 2):

You must read [Diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) . Under the Approaches heading, for CPP, your case is clearly mentioned, your observation matches the one explained there.

Comment: That's a good link, but as you said; it shows the observation. I wanted to know **reason** behind it. What happens under the hood (in brief).

Comment: I think the article about [Virtual Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) could be more instrumental for a deeper understanding of what happens under the hood.

Comment: Wikipedia links are not answers.

Answer (score 2):

The standard requires that `d.i` must be ambiguous in this case. ISO/IEC 14882:2003 section 10.1.6 covers classes with virtual and non-virtual base classes of a given type.